# WKWebview goes blank after device rotation

Tags: ios, swift3, wkwebview, screen-rotation

I'm making a scrollview with multiple subviews, includes collectionView, webView, and normal UIview. As far as Ive read through, it is not recommended to put webview inside a scrollview. But it is still ok to add webview as subview inside the scrollview.

The requirement is that the webview will dynamically load the content onClick. So, at first, there was a bit of issue trying to dynamically resize the height of the webview as per the content size. The height gets added extra pixels after every rotation. But somehow managed to make it work using webview.sizeToFit() in the viewDidLayoutSubviews().

But now the problem is that, the content of the webview disappears after every 2 rotation of the device. The content should still be there because the webview's frame size didnt change after roation, just the texts inside disappear.

There is not other error as to why the webview is showing blank for after rotated.This is my viewdidlayoutsubview.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    webView.frame.size.height = 1
    webView.frame.size = webView.sizeThatFits(.zero)
    webView.sizeToFit()
}
```

Not sure how to solve.

Comment: can you post a debug hierarchy screen Shot?

Comment: Hello @Reinier Melian, this is the portait [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2KLCHaQGvD9dlFTVEw0WVR1Q0k/view?usp=sharing) and landscape [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2KLCHaQGvD9ZUZwSEhlTEhWWTQ). I just started learning ios dev a few weeks ago, so not sure if this is the correct debug hierarchy im supposed to post.
For now ive somehow managed to workaround the issue by refreshing the views upon screen rotation with *viewWillTransition*. But still no clue abt what made the webview content disappeared. 

Thank you in advance :D

Comment: the images are ok, but don't help, so this is a real project or test project?

Comment: This is a real project. Could it be that the debug hierarchy doesnt help is because the views are created programatically?

Answer (score 0):

I will just answer myself here, since the solution last time was still working well for this. Refresh the view layouts on  in the override func *viewWillTransition*. As per apple's doc, "UIKit calls this method before changing the size of a presented view controller's view". So Ive refreshed all the subview's before changing the orientation.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator){
   super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
   //code to refresh the views
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line below wkwebview code

i named var = webView so,

webView.autoresizingmask = [.flexiblewidth,.flexibleheight]

hope it works.